# How to add "ignore-certificate-errors" in webview2 WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.8, webview2

I am trying to convert WPF chrome browser component to WebView2 .

Chrome have this settings :

```
        if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
        {
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
        }
```

How to Add this in WebView2.

I see some links about it ,but it say it will be support later [microsoft-edge-webview2-ignore-certificate-errors](https://forum.devolutions.net/topics/36001/microsoft-edge-webview2-ignore-certificate-errors) . is this supported ?

Comment: Why are you getting the error?  Ignore certificate was used years ago.  Since most servers are using TLS (HTTPS) for connections and you cannot use HTTP any more.  So how do you ignore a Certificate when you are required to use HTTPS.  It does make sense to use specific certificates and ignore others.   But is that what you are really asking?

Comment: Website is managed by other internal team . and now it not have valid certificate . it will be fixed in final release or in prod :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supported in the current release of `WebView2` (version 1.0.1343.22).

The way you do it is:

After the `WebView2`is initialized, you subscribe to the `ServerCertificateErrorDetected` event, like this:

```
webView.CoreWebView2.ServerCertificateErrorDetected += WebView_ServerCertificateErrorDetected;
```

then inside that eventhandler, you tell it to ignore the error:

```
void WebView_ServerCertificateErrorDetected(object sender, CoreWebView2ServerCertificateErrorDetectedEventArgs e)
{
   CoreWebView2Certificate certificate = e.ServerCertificate;
   e.Action = CoreWebView2ServerCertificateErrorAction.AlwaysAllow;
}
```

There's more advanced options available  (like only ignore some certificates), but if you just want to allow all certificates, then this should work.

**However the question still remains: Why are the certificates invalid and should they be ignored? You can make even self-signed certificates valid on local systems, so they don't throw errors (look it up).**

Comment: thanks it works 
and for the Question , Website is managed by other internal team . and now it not have valid certificate . it will be fixed in final release or in prod :)

Comment: Sounds good. In that case, you could make the code conditional, so it's removed in final release. Then the final release will be secure, while you can connect while developing.